# Why can't I access auth.currentUser inside of a ternary if statement? React, firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-authentication, ternary

My goal is to show the signout button when a user is logged in, and the sign in button if not.

If I use this code, auth.currentUser is accessible:

```
const JoinCard = () => {
  const auth = getAuth(app);
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const usersRef = collection(db, "users");

  const signInWithGoogle = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(auth.currentUser);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    const { uid, photoURL, displayName } = auth.currentUser;
    await addDoc(usersRef, {
      uid: uid,
      photoURL: photoURL,
      displayName: displayName,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-[85vw] h-[30vh] m-2 rounded-2xl drop-shadow-xl flex justify-center items-center p-2 bg-white/75">
      <button className="sign-in" onClick={signInWithGoogle}>
        Sign in with Google
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

function SignOut() {
  return (
    auth.currentUser && (
      <button className="sign-out" onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>
        Sign Out
      </button>
    )
  );
}

export default JoinCard;
```

However if I place the SignIn button in a ternary, auth.currentUser is now null. Why is that?

```
 return (
    <div className="w-[85vw] h-[30vh] m-2 rounded-2xl drop-shadow-xl flex justify-center items-center p-2 bg-white/75">
      {user ? (
        <SignOut />
      ) : (
        <button className="sign-in" onClick={signInWithGoogle}>
          Sign in with Google
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase automatically persists the user credentials on most browser environments, and restores them when the page/app reloads. This requires that it makes a call to the server however, to check for example of the account was disabled. This means that on the initial load the `currentUser` variable will be `null`, as the (asynchronous) call to the server hasn't completed yet.

The `useAuthState` hook wraps an auth state listener that you can see in the first code fragment in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user). This construct ensures that your code can respond to auth state changes, which fits perfectly with the reactive nature of ReactJS.

So if you want to ensure you app shows the current user state, make sure to always respond to the `useAuthState` hook - or directly use an auth state change listener.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I did eventually go for the useAuthState route, but this still doesn't explain why currentUser was out of scope in the ternary but not outside of it (without changing any other code).